# Best way to read very huge Excel [XSLX] using node Or ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, node.js

I need to parse XLXS which is around 25 MB in size [have about 1 million records] . I read through lot of Node modules including below

```
https://github.com/trevordixon/excel.js

https://github.com/dkiyatkin/node-office
```

I also tried using the Ruby with Roo

```
https://github.com/Empact/roo
```

But they are hanging. Is there any suggestion to do this Or I need to end up in splitting the files in to multiple small pieces ?

While Using "oxcelix"  as per "carlosramireziii" suggestion!

" https://github.com/gbiczo/oxcelix "

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > require 'oxcelix'
 => true 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > s = Oxcelix::Workbook.new("/var/www/fullcontact/current/public/uploads/fileupload/filename/Book1.xlsx")
Killed
root@createresume:/var/www/fullcontact/current/public/uploads# irb
2.0.0-p247 :001 > require 'oxcelix'
 => true 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > s = Oxcelix::Workbook.new("/var/www/fullcontact/current/public/uploads/fileupload/filename/Book1.xlsx")
Errno::EEXIST: File exists - /var/www/fullcontact/shared/uploads/tmp
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `fu_mkdir'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:174:in `block in mkdir'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:173:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:173:in `mkdir'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/oxcelix-0.3.2/lib/oxcelix/workbook.rb:52:in `initialize'
    from (irb):2:in `new'
    from (irb):2
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb:13:in `<main>'
2.0.0-p247 :003 > exit
root@createresume:/var/www/fullcontact/current/public/uploads# rm -rf tmp/
root@createresume:/var/www/fullcontact/current/public/uploads# irb
2.0.0-p247 :001 > require 'oxcelix'
 => true 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > s = Oxcelix::Workbook.new("/var/www/fullcontact/current/public/uploads/fileupload/filename/Book1.xlsx")
Killed
root@createresume:/var/www/fullcontact/current/public/uploads#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the parsing library you use, your parsing routine might be attempting to turn the entire XLXS file into objects which then get stored in memory. For very large files, this could result in the hanging behavior that you are seeing.

One option which is frequently used to avoid this issue is to use a [**SAX parser**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML). Rather than trying to parsing the entire file at once, a SAX parser will sequentially read each piece of the document one bit at a time which won't result in the memory explosion of the former method.

<strike>For parsing XLSX documents, you should try the Oxcelix gem for Ruby which uses a SAX parser under the covers.</strike>

https://github.com/gbiczo/oxcelix

UPDATE:

Unfortunately, the Oxcelix gem does use SAX parsing under the covers but it then returns the result of the parsing as an array, which, in the case of very large files, will blow up in memory.

If you were able to convert your Excel sheet into XML, then you could make use of any SAX-style parser. In this case, I would recommend this fork of [SAXMachine](https://github.com/gregwebs/sax-machine), which allows you to create declarative models and returns them sequentially using the `lazy` option.

Comment: Thanks for very quick answer. I tried the Gem , but the Process was killed auto. I pasted the console response above.

Comment: I updated my answer above.. It seems that the Oxcelix gem does use a sax parser, but then it tries to turn the result of the parsing routine into objects in memory, which is likely causing your process to be killed. I gave an alternative solution to try which is a bit trickier but could work.

Comment: : Thanks for quick reply , I will give a try with that. Is there any way to split the files in multiple pieces through Ruby ?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to do that offhand. I would suspect that you might end up with the same problem since most of the parsing libraries would probably try to put the whole document into memory to do the split.

Comment: Yes , I understood. I will try few more libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a very large xml file. Performance wise it is best to "cut" it down into smaller junks and process each of them separately.

Comment: : Is there any way to split the files in to multiple pieces through Ruby Or Node?

Comment: I did split it into chunks of 50 items pér block with Ruby, but that number varies of course depending on your available resources. With your XLS file I would suggest that you maybe take a few hundred rows at a time by defining a range of how many rows to select at a time.